# Weird ASCII/Unicode Character

Tags: c++, unicode, ascii

[Peter Thiel's CS183 Notes](http://bit.ly/thiel-pdf) has a filename with the ASCII string: "Peter Thiel's CS183.pdf" or at least that is how it prints out in Windows Explorer. However, while debugging my program, I noticed that the `'` character isn't the plain apostrophe, it has a (unsigned char) value of 146, not the expected 39.

To test to see if it was a bug in my program, I renamed the file and erased the character and retyped apostrophe. Sure enough, this time my program displayed the correct value. I reasoned therefore that it must be a Unicode character (since I don't see it in the ASCII table). However, it isn't a multibyte character because the next byte in the string is an 's'.

Can someone help explain whats going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is believing this string is ASCII.

If you are using a Windows machine with character encoding CP-1252 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), then your "code" 146 is a
kind of quote (see the table at the wikipedia page).

Answer (score 1):

It's a Right single quotation mark instead of a Single quote:

http://www.ascii-code.com/

Like you said, 39 is a Single quote, but the file must have been named using a Right single quotation mark, decimal value 146 in the Windows Latin-1 extended characters, CP-1252.

Comment: It's not ASCII; it's Windows CP1252. ASCII is only below 128.

Comment: @prosfilaes I think you're right, http://www.asciitable.com/" has it listed as something else entirely.

Comment: @chacham15 ASCII was *never* updated, so it's impossible to have an outdated ASCII table.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, Ascii *was* updated (in 1968 and 1986). But usually the mess around Ascii is caused by confusing Ascii with various other codes that have characters beyond position 127.

Comment: It's good, I learned something as well, and am glad for the correction, which is the point of this whole thing ;)

Comment: @chacham15 what people often refer to as 'extended ascii' is not ascii at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is the right single quote mark in the Windows codepage CP1252, neither in ASCII (or ISO-8859-1) or any form of Unicode.